# CSS links work on github pages but not locally?

Tags: html, css

Does anybody know why on github pages, a link `/css/main.css` works, but when I run it as `file:///path/to/file.html` the link doesn't locally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your git checkout directory isn't the *root* directory of your hard disk. And `/` starts at the root.

Comment: I suppose I shall just have to change the code before upload?

Comment: Most people have a development environment that resembles the live environment as much as possible. Installing a webserver is a basic requirement.